# React-native - passing values between components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I know there's many similar threads but since I have a hard time understanding the answers I figured I might try with my own code and see if I can make any sense of the answers.

I just set this up really simple to test it out. I have an Index file that is opened when I start the app. In the index I have testValue in this.state:

Update:

In SignIn:

```
 constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
          credentials: {
            username: "",
            password:"",

          }
        }
        this.navigate = this.props.navigation.navigate;

    {...}

    this.navigate("main", {
                credentials: this.state.username,

              });

In main:
    constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        this.params = this.props.navigation.state.params;
        this.navigate = this.props.navigation.navigate;

       {...}

    render() {
        console.log(this.params.username);
```

Comment: you didn't show the code where you are passing the prop. show the render method where TestIndex is used

Comment: I am not passing the prop. How do I do that? I just have it in this.state

Comment: If you want 'testValue' to be a prop, then when you use `TestIndex` from `Index`, you have to do something like `<TestIndex testValue={this.state.testValue}>`

Comment: required reading https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component

Comment: <TestIndex testValue={this.state.testValue}> Do I pass this on somehow with the button or just paste that somewhere? Yes, I understand I sound like a moron but I just can't wrap my head around this.

Comment: @Liam not sure what you mean with relative but the only way to get to TestIndex is from Index.

Comment: I edited the OP. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098376/pass-data-between-pages-in-react-native/50099561#50099561

Comment: @omprakash8080 I updated OP to fit that explanation. I am getting "Typeerror: undefined is not an object (evaluating this.params.username)". Any idea?

Comment: @J.Doe Can you share the code snippet?

Comment: @omprakash8080 I managed to get it to work. The problem was at the switchnavigator.

Comment: @J.Doe Okay...:-)

Answer (score 1):

This would actually log the testValue. All you have to do is to pass the testValue state as a prop in TestIndex component. Like this:

**Index.jsx**

```
export default class Index {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            testValue: 'hello'
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <TestIndex testValue={this.state.testValue} />
    }
}
```

**TestIndex.jsx**

```
export default class TestIndex extends React.Component {
    index() {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("index")
    }
    handleClickMain = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("index");
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn} onPress={() => {
                    console.log(this.props.testValue) //here's where I want it to log testValue from the index file
                    this.handleClickIndex()
                }
                }>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel like I'm very close with your response, thanks for that. I have (a lot) more than that in the index render though and when I do that I just go directly to the TextIndex file instead of clicking my way there. Is it possible to  return <TestIndex testValue={this.state.testValue} /> within the button {} or should I createClass somehow? Again, thanks for your comment, I really thought I got it this time