# Pass Data between Pages in React native

Tags: react-native, navigation

Im new to react native and I'm stuck at following.

Im performing navigation (when clicked on alert view button) using the code below.

```
const {navigation} = this.props.navigation;
…
.
.
 { text: 'Done', onPress:() => {
              navigate.push(HomeScreen);}
```

How can I pass data to another Page in React native? Can I declare the parameter global and just assign to it?

What would be the correct way of performing this and how would I go about it?

Comment: Are you using `react-navigation` ?

Answer (score 29):

> ## Note
>
> This answer was written for `react-navigation: "3.3.0"`. As there are newer versions available, which could bring changes, you should make sure that you check with the actual [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/).

Passing data between pages in `react-navigation` is fairly straight forward. It is clearly explained in the documentation [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html)

For completeness let's create a small app that allows us to navigate from one screen to another passing values between the screens. We will just be passing strings in this example but it would be possible to pass numbers, objects and arrays.

## `App.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import AppContainer from './MainNavigation';
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppContainer />
    )
  }
}
```

## `MainNavigation.js`

```
import Screen1 from './Screen1';
import Screen2 from './Screen2';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

const screens = {
  Screen1: {
    screen: Screen1
  },
  Screen2: {
    screen: Screen2
  }
}

const config = {
  headerMode: 'none',
  initialRouteName: 'Screen1'
}

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator(screens,config);
export default createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

## `Screen1.js` and `Screen2.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class Screen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  }
});
```

Here we have 4 files. The `App.js` which we will import the `MainNavigation.js`. The `MainNavigation.js` sets up a `StackNavigator` with two screens, `Screen1.js` and `Screen2.js`. `Screen1` has been set as the initial screen for our `StackNavigator`.

## Navigating between screens

We can navigate from `Screen1` to `Screen2` by using

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen2');
```

and we can go back to `Screen1` from `Screen2` by using

```
this.props.navigation.goBack();
```

So code in `Screen1` becomes

```
export default class Screen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title={'Go to screen 2'} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen2')} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

And code in `Screen2` becomes:

```
export default class Screen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title={'Go back'} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Now we can navigate between `Screen1` and `Screen2`

## Sending values from `Screen1` to `Screen2`

To send a value between `Screen1` and `Screen2`, two steps are involved. First we have to send it, secondly we have to capture it.

We can send a value by passing it as a second parameter. Notice how the text value is contained in an object.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen2', {text: 'Hello from Screen 1' });
```

And we can capture it in `Screen2` by doing the following, the first value in `getParams` is the `key` the second value is the default value.

```
const text = this.props.navigation.getParams('text','nothing sent');
```

So `Screen1` now becomes

```
export default class Screen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button 
         title={'Go to screen 2'} 
         onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen2',  { 
           text: 'Hello from screen 1' 
         })} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

And code in `Screen2` becomes:

```
export default class Screen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const text =  this.props.navigation.getParam('text', 'nothing sent')
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{text}</Text>
        <Button 
         title={'Go back'} 
         onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

## Sending values from `Screen2` back to `Screen1`

The easiest way I have discovered to send a value from `Screen2` to `Screen1` is to pass a function to `Screen2` from `Screen1` that will update the state in `Screen1` with the value that you want to send

So we can update `Screen1` to look like this. First we set an initial value in state. Then we create a function that will update the state. Then we pass that function as a parameter. We will display the captured value from `Screen2` in a `Text` component.

```
export default class Screen1 extends React.Component {

  state = {
    value: ''
  }

  receivedValue = (value) => {
    this.setState({value})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button 
          title={'Go to screen 2'} 
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen2', {
            text: 'Hello from Screen 1', 
            receivedValue: this.receivedValue } 
            )} />
          <Text>{this.state.value}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Notice that we are passing the function `receivedValue` in the same way that we passed the `text` earlier.

Now we have to capture the value in `Screen2` and we do that in a very similar way that we did previously. We use `getParam` to get the value, remembering to set our default. Then when we press our **Go back** button we update it to call the `receivedValue` function first, passing in the text that we want to send back.

```
export default class Screen2 extends React.Component {

  render () {
    const text =  this.props.navigation.getParam('text', 'nothing sent');
    const receivedValue = this.props.navigation.getParam('receivedValue', () => {});
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button 
          title={'Go back'} 
          onPress={() => {
            receivedValue('Hello from screen 2')
            this.props.navigation.goBack()
          }} />
          <Text>{text}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

## Alternatives to using `getParam`

It is possible to not use the `getParam` method and instead access the values directly. If we were to do that we would not have the option of setting a default value. However it can be done.

In `Screen2` we could have done the following:

```
const text = this.props.navigation.state.params.text;
const receivedValue = this.props.navigation.state.params.receivedValue;
```

## Capturing values in lifecycle events (`Screen1` to `Screen2`)

`react-navigation` allows you to capture values using the lifecycle events. There are a couple of ways that we can do this. We could use `NavigationEvents` or we could use listeners set in the `componentDidMount`

Here is how to set it up using `NavigationEvents`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation'; // you must import this


export default class Screen2 extends React.Component {

    state = {
      text: 'nothing passed'
    }

  willFocusAction = (payload) => {
    let params = payload.state.params;
    if (params && params.value) {
      this.setState({value: params.value});
    }
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <NavigationEvents
        onWillFocus={this.willFocusAction}

        />
        <Text>Screen 2</Text>
        <Text>{this.state.text}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Here is how to do it using listeners in the `componentDidMount`

```
export default class Screen2 extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount () {
    // we add the listener here
    this.willFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', this.willFocusAction);
  }

  componentWillUmount () {
    // we remove the listener here
    this.willFocusSubscription.remove()
  }

  state = {
    text: 'nothing passed'
  }

  willFocusAction = (payload) => {
    let params = payload.state.params;
    if (params && params.value) {
      this.setState({value: params.value});
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Screen 2</Text>
        <Text>{this.state.text}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

## Passing navigation via components

In the above examples we have passed values from screen to screen. Sometimes we have a component on the screen and we may want to navigate from that. As long as the component is used within a screen that is part of a navigator then we can do it.

If we start from our initial template and construct two buttons. One will be a functional component the other a React component.

## `MyButton.js`

```
// this is a functional component
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export const MyButton = ({navigation, value, title}) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Screen2', { value })}>
      <View style={styles.buttonStyle}>
        <Text>{title}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonStyle: {
    width: 200,
    height: 60,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  }
});
```

## `MyOtherButton.js`

```
// this is a React component
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default class MyOtherButton extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { navigation, value, title } = this.props; 
    return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Screen2', { value })}>
      <View style={styles.buttonStyle}>
        <Text>{title}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonStyle: {
    width: 200,
    height: 60,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'yellow'
  }
});
```

Regardless of the type of component, notice that navigation is a prop. We must pass navigation to the component otherwise it will not work.

## `Screen1.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { MyButton } from './MyButton';        
import MyOtherButton from './MyOtherButton';  

export default class Screen1 extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Screen 1</Text>
        <MyButton 
          title={'Press my button'} 
          navigation={this.props.navigation}
          value={'this is a string passed using MyButton'}
        />
        <MyOtherButton 
          title={'Press my other button'} 
          navigation={this.props.navigation}
          value={'this is a string passed using MyOtherButton'}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  }
});
```

Notice in `Screen1.js` as it is contained in a StackNavigator it will have access to `this.props.navigation`. We can pass that through to our component as a prop. As long as we use that in our component then we should be able to navigate by using the components own functionality.

```
<MyButton 
  title={'Press my button'} 
  navigation={this.props.navigation} // pass the navigation here
  value={'this is a string passed using MyButton'} 
/>
```

## Snacks

- Here is a snack [for passing params](https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/passing-values-between-screens).
- Here is a snack [for passing params and capturing in lifecycle events](https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/catching-values-with-navigation-listeners).
- Here is a snack [passing navigation to components](https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/passing-navigation-to-components)

Comment: Is there a way to pass values from screen1 to screen2 without firing the navigation?

Comment: There are many different ways, it really depends on your app set up. Simplest could be to use event emitters or AsyncStorage, more involved would be to use a redux setup. I would suggest writing up your situation into a new question so that you can clearly express everything that you need to do, as the comments on SO do not really allow a detailed discussion to take place. For one, code does not format nicely here; and secondly, you are limited to 600 characters, so it makes it hard to express oneself fully.

Comment: thank you for a detailed answer, I do understand now more about navigation getParam)))

Comment: How can I pass an object from a flatlist?

Answer (score 7):

**1) On Home Screen:-**

**Initialise:-**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.navigate = this.props.navigation.navigate; }
```

**Send:-**

```
this.navigate("DetailScreen", {
            name: "Detail Screen",
            about:"This is Details Screen Page"
          });
```

**2) On Detail Screen:-**

**Initialise:-**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.params = this.props.navigation.state.params;
}
```

**Retrive data:-**

```
console.log(this.params.name);
console.log(this.params.about);
```

Comment: If you are showing in any element, you also show like <Text>{this.params.name}</Text>

Comment: Thanks, nice and easy.

Answer (score 4):

```
const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;

…
.
.
 { text: 'Done', onPress:() => {
              navigate('homeScreen',...params);}
```

You can get those params like

```
const {params} = this.props.navigation.state
```

Answer (score 4):

HomeScreen.js

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen2',{ user_name: 'aaa',room_id:'100' });
```

Screen2.js

```
const params = this.props.route.params;
user_name = params.user_name;
room_id = params.room_id
```

Comment: How can I pass an object from a flatlist?

Answer (score 3):

You can easily send and receive your params with [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) like below

**Send params**:

```
{
   text: 'Done',
   onPress: () => {
       this.props.navigation.navigate(
           HomeScreen,
           {param1: 'value1', param2: 'value2'}
       );
   }
}
```

**Get params** in `HomeScreen`:

```
const { navigation } = this.props;
var param1 = navigation.getParam('param1', 'NO-VALUE');
var param2 = navigation.getParam('param2', 'NO-VALUE');
```

the `'NO-VALUE'` is default value, if there is not desired param

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that you are using react-navigation. So, in react-navigation we can pass data in two pieces:

1. Pass params to a route by putting them in an object as a second parameter to the navigation.navigate function:

   `this.props.navigation.navigate('RouteName', { /* params go here */ })`
2. Read the params in your screen component:

   `this.props.navigation.getParam(paramName, someDefaultValue)`

   **Alert Button**

   ```
       <Button
         title="Alert View"
         onPress={() => {
           this.props.navigation.navigate('alerts', {
             itemId: 86,
             otherParam: 'anything you want here',
           });
         }}
       />
   ```

**Screen:**

```
const itemId = navigation.getParam('itemId', 'NO-ID');
const otherParam = navigation.getParam('otherParam', 'some default value')
```

Answer (score 1):

**Screen 1:**

```
<Button title="Go Next"
onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SecondPage', { paramKey: userName })} />
```

**Screen 2:**

```
const SecondPage = ({route}) => {
    ....
    ....
    <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
        Values passed from First page: {route.params.paramKey}
    </Text>
    ....
    ....
}
```