# How to send data to other screen on item click of custom flat list

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, navigation, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to navigate to another screen when I click on one of the items on the flat list. I am new bee. I tried using stack Navigator but unable to do that. it's been 3 days stuck on this. I am using custom FlatList. Flat list is working fine, I am able to click on items of Flat List and get corresponding Items data as well. Now I want to send that data to another screen to display that data in detail view. I tried different methods but I am unable to access props where I am using onClick

**OrdersScreen.js**

```
export default class OrdersScreen extends Component {

static navigationOptions = {
    drawerIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
        <Icon name="home" style={{fontSize: 24, color:tintColor}}/>
    )
};

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        load : false,
    }
}

componentWillMount() {    
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
            load : true,
        }); 
    }, 3000);
}

getData() {
    return [
      {
        key: 1, title: 'Albert Einstein',
        description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore',
        image_url: 'http://vivirtupasion.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/DANI_PERFILzoomCircle.png'
      },
      {
        key: 2,
        title: 'Isaac newton',
        description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore',
        image_url: 'http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-jd5x3rFRLJc/VngrSWSHcjI/AAAAAAAAGJ4/ORPqZNDpQoY/s1600/Profile%2Bcircle.png'
      },
      {
        key: 3, title: 'Albert Einstein',
        description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore',
        image_url: 'http://vivirtupasion.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/DANI_PERFILzoomCircle.png'
      },
      {
        key: 4,
        title: 'Isaac newton',
        description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore',
        image_url: 'http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-jd5x3rFRLJc/VngrSWSHcjI/AAAAAAAAGJ4/ORPqZNDpQoY/s1600/Profile%2Bcircle.png'
      },
      {
        key: 5, title: 'Albert Einstein',
        description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore',
        image_url: 'http://vivirtupasion.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/DANI_PERFILzoomCircle.png'
      },
      {
        key: 6,
        title: 'Isaac newton',
        description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore',
        image_url: 'http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-jd5x3rFRLJc/VngrSWSHcjI/AAAAAAAAGJ4/ORPqZNDpQoY/s1600/Profile%2Bcircle.png'
      },
      {
        key: 7, title: 'Albert Einstein',
        description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore',
        image_url: 'http://vivirtupasion.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/DANI_PERFILzoomCircle.png'
      },
      {
        key: 8,
        title: 'Isaac newton',
        description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore',
        image_url: 'http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-jd5x3rFRLJc/VngrSWSHcjI/AAAAAAAAGJ4/ORPqZNDpQoY/s1600/Profile%2Bcircle.png'
      },
      {
        key: 9, title: 'Albert Einstein',
        description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore',
        image_url: 'http://vivirtupasion.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/DANI_PERFILzoomCircle.png'
      },
      {
        key: 10,
        title: 'Isaac newton',
        description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore',
        image_url: 'http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-jd5x3rFRLJc/VngrSWSHcjI/AAAAAAAAGJ4/ORPqZNDpQoY/s1600/Profile%2Bcircle.png'
      },
    ]
}
render() {
    if(this.state.load){
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Header style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
                    <Left style={{position: 'absolute',  flexDirection: 'row', left: 0, marginLeft: 20}}>
                        <Icon name="menu" style={{marginTop:20}} onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}/>
                        <Text style={styles.titleText}>  Orders!</Text>   
                    </Left>
                </Header>
                <View style={styles.contain}>
                    <CustomListview
                    itemList={this.getData()}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }else{
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Header style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
                    <Left style={{position: 'absolute',  flexDirection: 'row', left: 0, marginLeft: 20}}>
                        <Icon name="menu" style={{marginTop:20}} onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}/>
                        <Text style={styles.titleText}>  Orders!</Text>   
                    </Left>
                </Header>
            <View style={{ flex: 1 , justifyContent: 'center' , alignItems: 'center' , backgroundColor : '#ffffff'}}>
                <ActivityIndicator color={'grey'}/>
            </View>
            </View>

        );
    }
}
```

}

**CustomListview.js**

```
const CustomListview = ({ itemList }) => (
<View style={styles.container}>
    <FlatList
            data={itemList}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <CustomRow
                title={item.title}
                description={item.description}
                image_url={item.image_url}
                id={item.key}
            />}
        />

</View>);export default CustomListview;
```

**CustomRow.js**

```
const CustomRow = ({ id, title, description, image_url }) => (
<TouchableHighlight onPress={()=> {
    Toast.show(id + " Pressed", Toast.LONG);
}}>
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image source={{ uri: image_url }} style={styles.photo} />
        <View style={styles.container_text}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>
                {title}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.description}>
                {description}
            </Text>
        </View>
    </View>
</TouchableHighlight>);export default CustomRow;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass Data between Pages in React native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098376/pass-data-between-pages-in-react-native)

Comment: No I read that before. I have created components separately and now want to access prop and navigation there

Comment: You just have to pass the navigation prop to your component and the follow the above post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your FlatList:

```
onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate('destinationScreen', {data: item.YourData}); }}
```

then receive the data in your destinationScreen:

```
<Text>{this.props.navigation.state.params.data}</Text>
```

Dont forget to include the destinationScreen in your navigator in App.js:

```
 const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
        {
          Home: HomeScreen,
          Details: Screen1,
          destinationScreen: Screen2
        },
        {
          initialRouteName: "Home"
        }
      );
```

Comment: Yeah solved it by passing the reference and createStackNavigator

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass the value when you will navigate from one screen to another screen as below.

```
let data = {} // You can add your data into it
this.props.navigation.navigate('SCREENNAME', {data})
```

You can put above code into **onPress** of **TouchableHighlight**. And send data to your next screen.

Into the next screen, you can access the data as below:

```
let data = this.props.navigation.state.params.data
```

Comment: I am using this line. this.props.navigation.navigate('HelloWorld'); but it didn't move to that screen. Do I need to add in createStackNavigator(); ?

Comment: You can checkout https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html for stackNavigator.

Comment: `const appScreens = createStackNavigator({
    Hello: HelloWorld,
  })
  
AppRegistry.registerComponent('reactNav', () => appScreens); this.props.navigation.navigate('Hello');                                                                
  still this is not working`