# How to catch the params from this.props.navigation.navigate?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, expo

Now I am trying to get Params from a parent component in child component, but I couldn't.

I am using "react-navigation" and then in parent component, I did code like below.

```
renderShopList() {
return shopLists.map((value, index) => {
  const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      key={index}
      onPress={() => {
        if (value.genre === '飲食') {
          navigate('Restaurant', 'food');
```

And in child component, I tried to use

```
"Console.log(this.props.navigation.navigate.params);"
```

but I could catch "undefined" state.

How to get correct params from parent component?

Comment: show me your stack navigator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass Data between Pages in React native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098376/pass-data-between-pages-in-react-native)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can u try

```
 this.props.navigation.state.params
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply! and help me!
I tried that code in my code having problem, so I can get correct params!
Thank you a lot.