# How to passing my inserted id from firebase to next form

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, parameter-passing

im new to react native so i just can storing data from input text to firebase and making a login form.
i want to make an apps for survey, there a form input for survey data then passing the id survey to the next form  ( user form).
I can do that on CI or wordpress, but i cant do that on react native

the flow like this

**Survey form ---** *send the id inserted firebase* **---> User form** **-->** **Save Final Data**

Edited for show my code
Survey Form

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { 
    Button, 
    StyleSheet, 
    TextInput, 
    ScrollView, 
    ActivityIndicator, 
    View,
    Text,
    SafeAreaView,
    TouchableOpacity
    
} from 'react-native';
import {Ionicons} from "@expo/vector-icons"
import firebase from 'firebase';

export default class PostScreen extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.dbRef = firebase.firestore().collection('surveys');
    this.state = {
      usia: '',      
      kab: '',
      kec: '',
      desa: '',
      rw: '',
      rt: '',
      jekel: '',
      tps: '',
      isLoading: false
    };
  }

  inputValueUpdate = (val, prop) => {
    const state = this.state;
    state[prop] = val;
    this.setState(state);
  }

  storesurveys() {
    if(this.state.usia === ''){
     alert('Masukan usia anda!')
     
    }else {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: true,
      });      
      this.dbRef.doc(this.state.usia).set({
        usia: this.state.usia,
        kab: this.state.kab,
        kec: this.state.kec,
        desa: this.state.desa,
        rw: this.state.rw,
        rt: this.state.rt,
        jekel: this.state.jekel,
        tps: this.state.tps,
      }).then((res) => {
          
        this.setState({
            usia: '',
            kab: '',
            kec: '',
            desa: '',
            rw: '',
            rt: '',
            jekel: '',
            tps: '',
          isLoading: false,
        });
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Dummy')
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error("Error found: ", err);
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
        });
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    if(this.state.isLoading){
      return(
        <View style={styles.preloader}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#9E9E9E"/>
        </View>
      )
    }
    return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.header}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
            <Ionicons name="md-arrow-back" size={24} color="#D8D9DB"></Ionicons>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={{fontWeight:"500"}}>Formulir surveys</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
     <ScrollView style={styles.inputForm}>
        
        <View style={styles.inputGroup}>
          <TextInput
              placeholder={'usia'}
              value={this.state.usia}
              onChangeText={(val) => this.inputValueUpdate(val, 'usia')}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputGroup}>
          <TextInput
              placeholder={'kab'}
              value={this.state.kab}
              onChangeText={(val) => this.inputValueUpdate(val, 'kab')}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputGroup}>
          <TextInput
              placeholder={'kec'}
              value={this.state.kec}
              onChangeText={(val) => this.inputValueUpdate(val, 'kec')}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputGroup}>
          <TextInput
              placeholder={'desa'}
              value={this.state.desa}
              onChangeText={(val) => this.inputValueUpdate(val, 'desa')}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputGroup}>
          <TextInput
              placeholder={'rw'}
              value={this.state.rw}
              onChangeText={(val) => this.inputValueUpdate(val, 'rw')}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputGroup}>
          <TextInput
              placeholder={'rt'}
              value={this.state.rt}
              onChangeText={(val) => this.inputValueUpdate(val, 'rt')}
          />
        </View>
        
        <View style={styles.inputGroup}>
          <TextInput
              placeholder={'jekel'}
              value={this.state.jekel}
              onChangeText={(val) => this.inputValueUpdate(val, 'jekel')}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputGroup}>
          <TextInput
              placeholder={'tps'}
              value={this.state.tps}
              onChangeText={(val) => this.inputValueUpdate(val, 'tps')}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.button}>
          <Button
            title='Add Survey'
            onPress={() => this.storesurveys()} 
            color="#19AC52"
          />
        </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

User Form
NB : i need pass the survey form to my user form with the id inserted from survey

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { 
    Button, 
    StyleSheet, 
    TextInput, 
    ScrollView, 
    ActivityIndicator, 
    View,
    Text,
    SafeAreaView,
    TouchableOpacity
    
} from 'react-native';
import {Ionicons} from "@expo/vector-icons"
import firebase from 'firebase';

export default class PostScreen extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.dbRef = firebase.firestore().collection('penduduk');
    this.state = {
      nik: '',
      nama: '',
      tgl_lahir: '',
      usia: '',
      jekel: '',
      survey: '',
      isLoading: false
    };
  }

  inputValueUpdate = (val, prop) => {
    const state = this.state;
    state[prop] = val;
    this.setState(state);
  }

  storePenduduk() {
    if(this.state.nik === ''){
     alert('Masukan NIK anda!')
     
    }else if(this.state.nama === ''){
        alert('Masukan Nama anda!')
        
       }else {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: true,
      });      
      this.dbRef.doc(this.state.nik).set({
        nik: this.state.nik,
        nama: this.state.nama,
        tgl_lahir: this.state.tgl_lahir,
        usia: this.state.usia,
        jekel: this.state.jekel,
        survey : this.state.survey,
      }).then((res) => {
          
        this.setState({
            nik: nik,
            nama: '',
            tgl_lahir: '',
            usia: '',
            jekel: '',
            survey: '',
          isLoading: false,
        });
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Dummy')
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error("Error found: ", err);
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
        });
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    if(this.state.isLoading){
      return(
        <View style={styles.preloader}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#9E9E9E"/>
        </View>
      )
    }
    return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.header}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
            <Ionicons name="md-arrow-back" size={24} color="#D8D9DB"></Ionicons>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={{fontWeight:"500"}}>Formulir Penduduk</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
     <ScrollView style={styles.inputForm}>
        <View style={styles.inputGroup}>
          <TextInput
              placeholder={'nik'}
              value={this.state.nik}
              onChangeText={(val) => this.inputValueUpdate(val, 'nik')}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputGroup}>
          <TextInput
              placeholder={'nama'}
              value={this.state.nama}
              onChangeText={(val) => this.inputValueUpdate(val, 'nama')}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputGroup}>
          <TextInput
              placeholder={'tgl_lahir'}
              value={this.state.tgl_lahir}
              onChangeText={(val) => this.inputValueUpdate(val, 'tgl_lahir')}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputGroup}>
          <TextInput
              placeholder={'usia'}
              value={this.state.usia}
              onChangeText={(val) => this.inputValueUpdate(val, 'usia')}
          />
        </View>
       
        
        <View style={styles.inputGroup}>
          <TextInput
              placeholder={'jekel'}
              value={this.state.jekel}
              onChangeText={(val) => this.inputValueUpdate(val, 'jekel')}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputGroup}>
          <TextInput
              placeholder={'survey'}
              value={this.state.survey}
              onChangeText={(val) => this.inputValueUpdate(val, 'survey')}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.button}>
          <Button
            title='Add User'
            onPress={() => this.storePenduduk()} 
            color="#19AC52"
          />
        </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

Can someone giving me an example/source code/ documentation to do that?
thank you

Comment: Please post code you have tried

Comment: i have tried so many code and make me confused

Comment: Ok post code where you create user or created id for survey form

Comment: im done adding my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Screen

```
this.dbRef.doc(this.state.usia).set({
usia: this.state.usia,
    kab: this.state.kab,
    kec: this.state.kec,
    desa: this.state.desa,
    rw: this.state.rw,
    rt: this.state.rt,
    jekel: this.state.jekel,
    tps: this.state.tps,
  }).then((res) => {
    const insertedId = res.id
    this.setState({
        usia: '',
        kab: '',
        kec: '',
        desa: '',
        rw: '',
        rt: '',
        jekel: '',
        tps: '',
      isLoading: false,
    });
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Dummy', {id: insertedId})
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("Error found: ", err);
    this.setState({
      isLoading: false,
    });
  });
```

Second Screen :

```
render() {
    if(this.state.isLoading){
      const text =  this.props.navigation.getParam('id', 'new id');
      return(
        <View style={styles.preloader}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#9E9E9E"/>
        </View>
      )
    }
```

Must follow all rules of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54790847/10182897) answer so you can id on next screen

Comment: thank you, thast a full documentation with the way to get the inserted id, ill read that.

Comment: i have following the doc, but i cant go to the next screen ( form user), but when i delete the {id...} i can go to navigate the next screen. whats wrong with my code?

Comment: yes, i mean i call the 2nd screen on my app.js, then after that i call on 1st screen to navigate to 2nd screen, there is no error when the button clicked. the database also inserted but not going to 2nd screen

Comment: after i try it again, when the data successfully inserted, the1st screen not going to 2nd screen :(

Comment: @MdruidD did you check you check your second screen code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get inserted id after add();

```
firebase.firestore().collection("SurveyForm").add({
// inserted values
}). then((docRef) => { const insertedId = docRef.id }  })
```

Comment: then how i call the inserted id on my next form to use that to insert new data with the id?