# Pass parameters on back button React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I am trying to pass some information to the previous screen when the back button is pressed with React Native Navigation, however, I can't figure out how to pass params with the built in back button. When I use my own button, I find it fairly straightforward as parameters can be passed to the route like so

```
<TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.container}
        onPress={() =>
          navigation.navigate('EditAsset', {
            data: 'some data',
            
          })
        }>
```

I want to pass some information to the previous screen when the back button is pressed. I tried doing it with `setParams` and then checking for `editUpdates` in `routes.params` on the previous screen, but that didn't seem to do the trick

```
navigation.setParams({
      editUpdates: 'someText',
    });
```

Here is the code from the AppStack where the navigator config is done

```
import React from 'react';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';

import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import EditAssetScreen from '../screens/EditAssetScreen';
import {TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-native';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const AppStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Plutus"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{header: () => null}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="EditAsset"
        component={EditAssetScreen}
        options={({navigation}) => ({
          title: 'Holding Details',
          // headerMode: 'none',
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#f9fafd',
            shadowColor: '#f9fafd',
            elevation: 0,
            shadowOpacity: 0,
          },
        })}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default AppStack;
```

In Summary, I navigate from screen A to B. Then make updates to screen B. Then navigate back to screen A. I would like to pass the updates made on screen B back to screen A.

Comment: Here is the soltuion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098376/pass-data-between-pages-in-react-native/54790847

Comment: can you show your implementations of back button

Comment: @sankasanjeewa It's done for you automatically I think. If I add the `headerMode: none` in the AppStack, then the back button dissappears.

Comment: @HydenPolikoff, I mean your custom back button

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible solution for it without using third-party library.

**Solution 1:**

You can use react-native BackHandler API.

First import

```
import {BackHandler} from "react-native"
```

Then add following code in your Screen B

```
useEffect(()=>{
 BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress",()=>{
 navigation.navigate("Screen A", {data: "paramData"});
 //You can add any other statements also 
 return true;
 })
},[])
```

**Solution 2:**

You can use React Navigation's navigation.addListener

First import

```
import {useState} from "react"
```

Then you need to add following code in your Screen B

```
useEffect(()=>{
     navigation.addListener("blur",()=>{
     navigation.navigate("Screen A", {data: "paramData"});
     //You can add any other statements also 
     })
},[])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just 2 days ago, I was stuck with the same issue, but could not find any solution, then I came up with redux. Just save the param data at the redux-state and then get it at the required component.

Answer (score 0):

Using state management like Redux is a good solution to prevent repeated issues in the future, as mentioned in the previous answer. But for anyone looking for a direct solution, you can override the back button like this:

```
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';

useEffect(() => {
   const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => { 
      navigation.navigate('SomeScreen', { data: 'some data' })
      return true;
   })

   return () => backHandler.remove()
}, [])
```